# как работают анонимные методы?

Tags: delphi, компиляция, delphi-xe, delphi-10-berlin

### Пример №1:

```
procedure TForm14.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SomeObj: TmyObj;
begin
  SomeObj := TmyObj.Create;    // создаем объект
  try
    SomeObj.Text := 'asdfasdfasd';
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
      begin
        Sleep(1000);  // ожидаем, чтобы гарантированно завершился метод btn2Click
        TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
          begin
            ShowMessage(SomeObj.Text); // пытаемся показать сообщение
          end)
      end).Start;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(SomeObj); // высвобождаем объект до его показа через функции синхронизации.
  end;
end;
```

Метод логично завершается ошибкой, поскольку когда очередь доходит до ShowMessage - объекта не существует. Если `FreeAndNil` заменить на `Free`, то в ShowMessage показывается пустая строка (ну, допустим, логично - объект уничтожен, память, которая была выделена под его поля приведена в "исходное" состояние).

### Пример №2

```
procedure TForm14.btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Text: string;
begin
  Text := 'asdfasdf';
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      Sleep(1000);
      TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
        begin
          ShowMessage(Text);
        end)
    end).Start;
  // выход из метода произойдет раньше, чем сработает ShowMessage
  // то есть - локальной переменной Text уже не будет
  // но всё отрабатывает!!!
  Text:='67563245';
end;
```

Показывается текст "67563245". Почему? Ведь строка - это по сути указатель. И так как она является локальной переменной, то должна (и будет) высвобождена при выходе из метода (в противном случае пошли бы утечки памяти). Соответственно де-юре пример №2 не отличается от примера №1, но выполняется...

Поведение с переменными других типов (integer, например) полностью соответствует тому, что происходит со string.

---

Как же все-таки компилятор работает с анонимными методами в Delphi?
Интересует как минимум - куда и как "запихиваются" переменные (включая интерфейсы), используемые в анонимном методе, раз они успешно доживают до начала работы кода этого анонимного метода?

Comment: то что переменная удаляется из таблицы, не значит ведь что память очищается? она помечается как свободная, но информацию в ней никто не меняет.

Comment: @teran Да, не очищается, а помечается как свободная. Но ведь тогда получается, что пользоваться этим небезопасно, потому что в любой момент времени память может быть распределена под другую переменную и всем станет плохо. Тем не менее - большАя часть кода (особенно в FMX) использует подобный подход. Вот мне и нужно понять - а как именно это организовано?

Comment: Анонимная функция это [замыкание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), которое захватывает внешние переменные. Захват работает для автоматических переменных (строки/интерфейсы) и очевидно, не может сработать для простых объектов, которые пользователь волен уничтожить в любой момент времени.

Comment: @kami, если мне память не изменяет, то у строк есть подсчет ссылок (пока они не меняются, там в -1 слове хранится длина, в -2 например число ссылок), так что никуда она не удаляется. Удаление строки произойдет по завершению работы анонимного метода. 

не совсем понятно, почему работает с int.

Comment: но судя по комментарию выше, понятно.

Comment: @zed, teran  А мне все же непонятно. Допустим, "в момент выполнения внешней функции создается экземпляр внутренней с новыми ссылками на переменные внешней функции". Ссылки объясняют, почему в примере 2 показывается "67563245", а не "asdfasdf" и объясняют почему переменные с управляемым временем жизни доживают до анонимного метода. Но как быть со ссылками на простые типы, тот же integer? они тоже уходят в метод по ссылке, т.к. имеют поведение аналогично примеру 2 со string. И доживают до выполнения, несмотря на отсутствие reference counting-а. А должны исчезнуть при выходе из внешней функции.

Comment: Это забота компилятора сделать так, чтобы они дожили. И тут дело не в подсчёте ссылок. Создаётся некая уникальная область видимости, в которой существуют эти переменные и доступ к ним имеют только внешняя и анонимная функции. Пока хотя бы одна из этих функций выполняется, переменные живут и могут быть изменены из любой из них. Т.е. анонимная функция пользуется не копией, а самой внешней переменной.

Comment: Этот же вопрос в англоязычной версии SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955052/how-are-anonymous-methods-implemented-under-the-hood

Comment: @zed, спасибо, вот мне и интересно было - как компилятор проявляет такую заботу. В дополнение - на одном из форумов мне дали ссылку http://pascal-study.blogspot.ru/2012/03/delphi.html , где раздел "Механизм привязки переменных" достаточно детально объясняет нужный мне механизм. Если кто возьмет на себя труд адаптировать это ответом для ruSO - будет здорово. Если совсем уж вкратце - локальные переменные, "транслируемые" в анонимный метод размещаются в куче, а не в стеке :)

Comment: Она не освобождается и не помечается, как свободная до тех пор пока к ней ещё есть обращение. А оно есть из потока. Можете перед выводом сообщения сделать ещё одно присвоение ей. Была бы она свободной это привело бы к ошибке. Этим и отличаются эти 2 примера. в первом вы объект сами убиваете... Сделайте это в потоке после вывода сообщения и будет работать, как второй.

Comment: Не используйте анонимные методы в Дельфи вообще никогда. Запихнули их из явы следуя моде. Они не нужны и только портят код.

Comment: @Eugene помимо вашего личного мнения хотелось бы фактов. Ссылки на известные проблемы, заведенные в quality.embarcadero.com багрепорты и так далее. Потому что в данном случае мое мнение (и мой опыт использования) говорит об обратном - анонимки это прелестно.

Answer (score 1):

Параметры, передаваемые в анонимную функцию оборачиваются в интерфейс.
В первом случае ссылка на объект внутри этого интерфейса ничего не знает о том, что объект уже уничтожен.

Во втором случае при сохранении строки будет увеличен счетчик ссылок на строку и она не будет уничтожена в момент выхода из метода. Поэтому все и работает.
Строка уничтожится, когда обнулится ее счетчик ссылок.

Comment: Ваш ответ не исчерпывающий, к сожалению. Переменные с управляемым временем жизни - действительно их поведение можно (относительно) объяснить. А вот как быть с простыми типами? Обратите внимание на комментарии к вопросу, собственно ответ там есть, но его нужно оформить ответом.

Comment: @kami вы можете попробовать сделать это сами

Comment: @PavelMayorov боюсь, мне квалификации не хватит, чтобы получился ответ, доступно (но в то же время - достаточно полно) излагающий этот механизм.